# postback call is not working in facebook messenger bot

Tags: node.js, facebook

I tried to get the postback call from payload in structured message from the facebook messenger bot . But whenever i tried with the sample code which they gave . That itself not working for me. I don't get the postback payload in the event. Normal message is working fine for me but the postback alone is not getting in the receiving json message. can anyone help me out .?

```
`if (messagingEvent.postback) {
          receivedPostback(messagingEvent);
}


function receivedPostback(event) {

  var payload = event.postback.payload;
  console.log("postback received ");
}


`
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting webhook, make sure you have registered the **`messaging_postbacks`** under Subscription Fields.